# Force Gradle to Assemble APK Without Clean

Tags: android, gradle, apk

Similar to [Force gradle to produce an apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721234/force-gradle-to-produce-an-apk) I want to force Gradle to produce an apk in case a previous build has been moved or deleted. I am curious if it is possible to do when the build directory has not been cleaned and source code has not changed. In other words, I don't want to recompile the entire source, just ensure that the apk is reproduced.

I am very inexperienced with Gradle. Looking over [Force Gradle to run task even if it is UP-TO-DATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42175235/force-gradle-to-run-task-even-if-it-is-up-to-date) the suggestion is to do something like the following:

```
mytask {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

However, I'm not sure which task I need to override nor how to do it. Packaging of the apk appears to occur during the step labelled `:app:packageRelease` in the console output:

```
> Task :app:packageRelease UP-TO-DATE
```

Is there a way to override `packageRelease` and add `outputs.upToDateWhen { false }` (if that is the correct way to do it)? A solution for all build types would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `./gradle assemble` task for that or run it specifically for a variant with `./gradle assembleDebug` or `./gradlew assembleRelease` etc.

Comment: Doesn't work. Build directory must be cleaned for `assemble` task to work.